# Why can't I make a POST request to my Node.js Express server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to create a basic user registration system. All I just want right now is that once I register with the HTML form, I should be able to console.log it in the server. I tried doing this using fetch but I get this error:

Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/api/register. URL scheme "file" is not supported.

This is the code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Registration</h1>
        <form id="reg-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        const form = document.getElementById('reg-form')
        
        form.addEventListener('submit', registerUser)
        
        async function registerUser(event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value
            
            const result = fetch('/api/register', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
            }).then(res => res.json())
            
            console.log(result)
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Express Server:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json({status: 'ok'})
})

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server up at 4000'))
```

I also tried doing the POST request directly from the HTML form element by setting the method attribute to POST and the action attribute pointing to the post route in my express server. When I try to submit the form, it redirects me to an empty page that says "Your file couldn't be accessed. It may have been moved, edited, or deleted."

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: can you add the folder structure of your project?

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the html file manually, not serving it from the server, so `/api/register` isn't going to your backend. Either serve the file from your server, or fetch `localhost:4000/api/register`

To serve your file from the server, you can do this:

```js
const path = require('path');

...

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../relative/path/to/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching **/api/register** try **http://localhost:4000/api/register**

> also to print the result try this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/register', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
```